# How to test login(which is using MySQL) in flask applicaton?

Tags: python, mysql, testing, flask

I've been learning flask following [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/intro-to-flask-signing-in-and-out--net-29982). Now I'm trying to test some parts of the application with python unittest. But I can't grasp how to test user login corrctly. Here's the code for the test I'm trying to do:

```
from intro_to_flask import app
from models import db
from models import User

class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://credentials/database'
    app.config['TESTING'] = True
    app.config['CSRF_ENABLED'] = False
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()


def tearDown(self):
    with app.app_context():
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()

def test_User_login(self):
    tester = app.test_client(self)
    u = User(firstname = 'testname', lastname = 'testlaname', email = 'test@example.com', password = 'pass')
    with app.app_context():
        db.session.add(u)
        db.session.commit()
    response = tester.post('/signin', data=dict(email = 'test@example.com', password = 'pass'), follow_redirects=True )
    self.assertIn(b'Profile', response.data) #User is redirected to profile page after loggin in which has giant Profile

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The test fails and it's clear, that login and the following redirect doesn't happen.

I added the following print statements to the test:

print(response)
print(response.data)

Which produced the following results:

## print(response)

```
<Response streamed [200 OK]>
```

## print(response.data)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Flask App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>

  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="logo">Image Hosting Test v 0.2</h1>
      <nav>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>

          <li><a href="/signup">Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="/signin">Sign In</a></li>

        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

    <div class="container">

  <h2>Sign In</h2>





  <form action="/signin" method=post>
    <div style="display:none;"><input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="1463805648##fcc7e953937a80b6744554aed86d092fcf70e1fb"></div>

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="test@example.com">

    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" value="">

    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Sign In">
  </form>


    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Can someone explain to me, what is wrong with my test?

Python version: 2.7.9
MySQL version: 5.7
Flask version: 0.10.1
OS Windows 10

Comment: that looks reasonable, can you put a print statement in the test and see what the response is?

Comment: I added print. It seems it doesn't follow redirects?

Comment: Ah, I think it's CSRF protections that is causing it. Try to disable it with setting 'WTF_CSRF_PROTECT=False'

Comment: Sorry, app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False

Comment: You were right! Thank you very much! I had no idea that I should use WTF_CSRF!

Comment: Done and done, posted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I think it's CSRF protections that is causing it. Try to disable it with setting

```
app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False
```